# Find divisible integers from set

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inclusion-exclusion

Find the number of integers in the set {1,2...10^3} which are not divisible by 5 nor 7 but are divisible by 3.

My attempt:
floor(10^3/3) - floor(10^3/21) - floor(10^3/15) - floor(10^3/105) = 211

Answer shows that its 229.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You applied inclusion exclusion wrongly it should be

$$\lfloor 10^3/3\rfloor - \lfloor10^3/21\rfloor - \lfloor10^3/15\rfloor + \lfloor10^3/105\rfloor$$

Comment: oh yes! thanks.